# Does the .vhd file extension have two different meanings?

Tags: vhdl

I am in the first week of a VHDL class. I am using Notepad++ to write my first module. When I save the file as a .vhd, it shows up in my folder as a 'Hard Disk Image File' instead of the desired VHDL file.

Likewise, when I download one of the example files from my instructor (also a .vhd file), it becomes a Hard Disk Image File upon completion of download.

How can a file extension have two different meanings? How do I get the files to save like I want them to (as VHDL files, NOT Hard Disk Image Files)?

Comment: The vhd extension can be a VM Ware hard drive.  So if you double click it then the OS will try to start  VM Ware.  But if you open the program you will use to read the file and then use that to open your vhd file it will work fine.  What program are you going to use to try to read your chd files?

Comment: Why are you saving these files as .vhd if you could just save them as .vhdl? A file extension does nothing magical, it's just a few letters in the name of the file and Windows just *assumes* the extension matches its contents. You can name any file .vhd and Windows will call it whatever it has been instructed a .vhd is supposed to be. If you installed other software that uses the .vhd extension for disk images, then that's what Windows will say they are, even if they happen to be VHDL files and you can just treat them like that, or associate appropriate software with it with Open With...

Comment: I will be using either Notepad++ or Vivado to open the files. I guess I will just open the files from either of those two programs or use Open With.

The reason I am saving them as .vhd is because that is the default when I select 'VHSIC Hardware Description Language file' from the 'Save as type' dropdown from the Windows Explorer save screen

Comment: Somebody (Microsoft?) collared the extension for their own use without considering if it was already in use... You can fix the Windows Explorer file associations to tell your computer to not do that.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you work on Windows. That operating system, more exactly its explorer, decides by the extension of the file name, which icon and file type to show. However, this is just cosmetic.

File names are just "labels" on a block of bytes. The meaning of the contents depends on its interpretation. If you save some ASCII characters in a file, you can call this a text file, a programming source file, or whatever your intent is.

"VHD" can have many meanings. One of them is "Virtual Hard Drive" that is used by software providing virtual machines, for example VirtualBox. Another one is "VHDL Source", as you have. I'm sure, there are more.

There are some alternatives for you, for example:

1. Ignore the icon and type shown in the explorer. Give the file to your translator/simulator or whatever needs to read it.
2. Assign another default application to the extension of the file name.
3. Use "VHDL", or better "vhdl" as extension.

Renaming a file does not change its contents. For example, you cannot rename a spreadsheet file ("XLSX" with Microsoft Office Excel) to a document's name ("DOCX" with Microsoft Office Word) and it magically becomes a document.

Just as an possibly enlighting experiment: Create an empty file (0 bytes), and name it "test.txt". It will be shown as a text file. Now rename it to "test.docx" (accept the warning and answer "yes"), and it will be shown as Word document. Now again rename it to "test.exe" and it will be shown as an application. See, the explorer kind of lies to you.

Another cool experiment: Create a Word document with some words in it and save it as "test.docx". It is shown as a Word document, of course. Rename it to "test.zip" and it will be shown as a compressed archive. Now comes the funny part: double click it to open it. And OMG, *it is* a compressed archive! You can investigate the structure of it, just don't change it, or you will most probably damage the document.

BTW, Linux systems decide by the contents, which file type to assume.